# "The required file is missing. It is part of the following package: fancyhdr"

Tags: errors, packages

About a month ago I downloaded LaTeX and have been doing a few simple projects from the Beginner's Guide by Kottwitz.

Yesterday I copied and pasted a LaTeX style file from a mathematics journal. But, when I try to compile it, I get the dialog box message saying:

> The required file is missing.  It is part of the following package: fancyhdr.

When I click on "install" and try again, I still get the same error message.  I need to know where to get this `fancyhdr` package, and where to put it on my computer.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome! Are you using MikTeX?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MikTex, it won't install a package while your text file is open, so close it. Then open package manager, and scroll down to fancyhdr, and install it. This should install it automatically in the right place.

Comment: @hsporn Since `Stephen's` response worked, **for the benefit of other readers**, you may want to mark his response as an answer.